# Detect a copy/paste event

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any event in VBA that could wake a certain procedure?

Here is what i want to achieve:
When I copy a cell, its address will be stored as string(e.g. "Sheet1 A1"), and when the content is pasted, a comment would be added to the paste target cell. The content of the comment is the string stored i.e. "Sheet1 A1".